# running two javascript functions on load, one cancels the other out

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am a beginner with javascript and I am trying to make sure both updateStyle AND changeColor work, but when I add changeColor() at the end, it works but then updateStyle() doesn't work, how can I make them both happen on load? updateStyle changes all H1 tags to be comic sans and changeColor makes every letter in H1 a different random color, in an ideal world: both of these things would happen! As the code is below, every letter in H1 is a different color but the font stays on auto. If I delete changeColor() (at the end) then H1 is always in comic sans. This is for a google extension if that is relevant.

```
'use strict'

let fontOverwrite = 'h1 {font-family: Comic Sans MS !important}'
let transformOverwrite = 'h1 {text-transform:uppercase}'

// if we don't have the styleDom, create it
let styleDom = document.getElementById('comic-sans-everything-style')
if (!styleDom) {
  styleDom = document.querySelector('h1').appendChild(document.createElement('style'))
  styleDom.id = 'comic-sans-everything-style'
  styleDom.rel = 'stylesheet'
  styleDom.type = 'text/css'
}
const updateStyle = () => {
  window.chrome.storage.sync.get(['status', 'uppercase'], (items) => {
    if (!window.chrome.runtime.error) {
      if (items.status && items.uppercase) {
        styleDom.innerText = fontOverwrite + transformOverwrite
      } else if (items.status) {
        styleDom.innerText = fontOverwrite
      } else {
        styleDom.innerText = ''
      }
    }
  })
}



// ADDED to make letters rainbow :)

function changeColor() {
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++)
{
    var innerText = paragraphs[i].innerHTML;
    var innerTextSplit = innerText.split("");
    paragraphs[i].innerText = "";

    var isHTMLElement = false;

    for(var j = 0; j < innerTextSplit.length; j++) {
        if(innerTextSplit[j] == "<")
          isHTMLElement = true;

        if(!isHTMLElement){
          var randomColor = "rgb(" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) + ");"
          innerTextSplit[j] = '<span style="color: ' + randomColor + '">' + innerTextSplit[j] + '</span>';
        }

        if(innerTextSplit[j] == ">")
            isHTMLElement = false;

    }

    innerTextSplit = innerTextSplit.join('');
    paragraphs[i].innerHTML += innerTextSplit;
}
}


//THIS is where i'm trying to make the functions happen, when they're both there ONLY changeColor() works


// run once on file load
updateStyle()
changeColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try and declare your function this way:

```
function updateStyle(){

window.chrome.storage.sync.get
(['status', 'uppercase'], 
(items) => {
if 
(!window.chrome.runtime.error) 
{
  if (items.status && 
  items.uppercase) {
  styleDom.innerText = 
  fontOverwrite + 
  transformOverwrite
  } else if (items.status) {
    styleDom.innerText = 
    fontOverwrite
  } else {
    styleDom.innerText = ''
  }
}
})
}
```

Secondly add ";" to the end of your function call

updatestyle();
changeColor;

Hope that helped